# calling javascript method for asp.net control not working

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, referenceerror

This is my JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    function ShowHelp() {
        window.open('../WebHelp/' + '<%= SessionManager.CurrentDictionaryId %>' + '/mweb.htm#cshelp/assetsdetail.htm', '', 'toolbar=no,directories=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes');
    }
    function RunPrint(values) {
        window.open('../Reports/Assets/AssetProfile.aspx?id=' + values, '', 'toolbar=no,directories=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes');
    }
});
```

And I have two `<asp:Hyperlink>` tags set like this:

```html
<asp:HyperLink ID="lnkHelp" runat="server" EnableViewState="False" ImageUrl="~/Images/Help.png"
        NavigateUrl="javascript:ShowHelp();" />
<asp:HyperLink ID="lnkPrint" ImageUrl="~/Images/PrintMed.png" runat="server" EnableViewState="false"
        NavigateUrl="javascript:GetSelectedToPrint();" />
```

When running the debugger tools in Chrome I get the message:

```
"Uncaught ReferenceError: ShowHelp is not defined"
"(anonymous function)"
```

I am fairly ignorant in javascript, but I feel like I know enough to read what is there and i don't see the issue.

Comment: Unwrap it from `$(document).ready`.

Comment: yup, just tried that and it worked. Any reference you can point me to as to why this happens?

Comment: It's because you're calling the methods from a `javascript:` URI, which uses global functions. By nesting the functions in another function, they are no longer global, and can't get called through said URI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you try to remove the $(document).ready(function(){ ?

that code is not needed if you are just wanting to create a function that will be fired after the controls were loaded (which is in  your case).

Comment: That worked, I tried it out just as you posted the answer. Thanks!